# Автозапуск исполняемого файла при подключении флешки

Tags: windows, автозапуск

Давным-давно не актуален *autorun.inf* в корне флешки, но кроме советов, связанных с его созданием я ничего не нашёл. Утилиты тоже не хотелось бы использовать.

Есть ли какой-то способ (скрипт какой-нибудь, например) организации постоянного автозапуска файла с флешки при её подключении *в условиях современности*? (советов от пользователей XP я начитался сполна... хотелось бы по существу: нужно, чтобы тема 'авторунилась' как на win7, так и на win10).

Возможно ли это вообще сейчас? (уже почти убедился в обратном)

P.S.: тег неуместен, но поставил его, исходя из мысли, что откликнувшиеся на этот тег сталкивались с вопросом создания автозапускалок разного рода.

Comment: Если это нужно для конкретных компьютеров, то можно настроить на них обработчик события подключения флешки. Средствами только флешки вы этого не сделаете. Если интересно и ещё актуально, могу расписать подробнее ответом - не так давно разрабатывал систему, которая выполняет определённые действия при подключении флешки с определённым ID при помощи планировщика задач Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Если и возможно, это - дыра в защите, которую стремительно закроют. И правильно сделают, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы администратор этого компьютера, либо домена к которому он подключен, то автозапуск включается групповыми политиками:

В разделе "Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Autoplay Policies" есть настройка "Automatically execute the autorun commands".  Начиная с 2-го сервиспака Windows XP, а так же в более новых версиях Windows она по умолчанию отключена. Вам же собственно нужно её включить.